# Number format in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: types, format, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration Version: 8.0.0.0-28.

Steps used in transformation:

- **Table input** (Connection: MySQL database)
- **Select values**
- **Insert/ Update** (Connection: MySQL database with the same data types as the input)

The input table has a column containing DOUBLE values.
I want to always keep two digits after the '**.**', examples:

```
1587.657 -> 1587.65
32.5 -> 32.50
693 -> 693.00
0 -> 0.00
```

I tried to change the format in the **Select values** step selecting **0.00** in the **meta-data** **format** field. It works when I click on **preview**. The problem is when I check the output table nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What data-type you have specified for the column and which data-type you have specified in meta-data tab ?

Comment: The data-types for both input and output tables are 'DOUBLE'. 
In the meta-data type I selected 'Number'.

Answer (score 0):

you have to match the meta data format in select value with the fields in the output, so you will get the result you expect

meta data format : Number (0.00)
output : Number (0.00)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).